# JavaScript/jQuery compare items within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

What I'm trying to do is compare items within an array to determine who get's listed first, for simplicity, in my mind all person data is stored in the same spot. I do not know if it would be easier or more efficient to separate this data.

Here is the array, shrunk down for readability.

```
var People = [{
    "Name": "Person1",
    "SN": "1",
    "First": "5",
    "Second": "6",
    "Third": "11",
    "Fourth": "7",
    "Fifth": "8",
    "Sixth": "1",
    "Seventh": "10",
    "Eigth": "4",
    "Ninth": "3",
    "Tenth": "2",
    "Eleventh": "13",
    "Twelth": "9",
    "Thirteenth": "12",
    "RDO1": 2,
    "RDO2": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Person2",
    "SN": "2",
    "First": "6",
    "Second": "5",
    "Third": "10",
    "Fourth": "9",
    "Fifth": "7",
    "Sixth": "8",
    "Seventh": "1",
    "Eigth": "4",
    "Ninth": "3",
    "Tenth": "2",
    "Eleventh": "13",
    "Twelth": "11",
    "Thirteenth": "12",
    "RDO1": 2,
    "RDO2": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Person3",
    "SN": "3",
    "First": "6",
    "Second": "9",
    "Third": "7",
    "Fourth": "10",
    "Fifth": "8",
    "Sixth": "5",
    "Seventh": "4",
    "Eigth": "2",
    "Ninth": "3",
    "Tenth": "13",
    "Eleventh": "11",
    "Twelth": "12",
    "Thirteenth": "1",
    "RDO1": 4,
    "RDO2": 5
}];
```

I've tried a bunch of nested if's, for loops, and functions that loop back to each other without success.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is it will grab the "First" choice and compare with the other People in the array and if someone else has the same "First" choice, it compares the SN number to see whichever is lower.

So in the above array when the code comes to Person3 and it sees "6" as the first choice, it looks to see if anyone else has 6 as their first choice and notices Person2 has it selected as well. It then compares the SN number and does not give 6 to Person3 because Person2 has a lower number, so then it moves on to Second for Person3 and does the same check all over again.

I've been smashing my head against this for a small while now and if anyone can shed any light on it I would be most grateful.

**edit - more code**

```
function getPref(index1) {

var sNumb = dsobj[index1].SN;

for (var i = 0; i < dsobj.length; i++) {
if (i != index1) { // Ensure you aren't checking the same person
  if (sNumb > dsobj[i].SN) { //Check to see if the SN is lower than the person you are checking
if (dsobj[index1].First === dsobj[i].First) {
  if (dsobj[index1].Second === dsobj[i].Second) {
    if (dsobj[index1].Third === dsobj[i].Third) {
      if (dsobj[index1].Fourth === dsobj[i].Fourth) {
        if (dsobj[index1].Fifth === dsobj[i].Fifth) {
          if (dsobj[index1].Sixth === dsobj[i].Sixth) {
            if (dsobj[index1].Seventh === dsobj[i].Seventh) {
              if (dsobj[index1].Eigth === dsobj[i].Eigth) {
                if (dsobj[index1].Ninth === dsobj[i].Ninth) {
                  if (dsobj[index1].Tenth === dsobj[i].Tenth) {
                    if (dsobj[index1].Eleventh === dsobj[i].Eleventh) {
                      if (dsobj[index1].Twelth === dsobj[i].Twelth) {
                        if (dsobj[index1].Thirteenth === dsobj[i].Thirteenth) {
                        } else {
                            endChoice = dsobj[index1].Thirteenth;
                        }
                      } else {
                        endChoice = dsobj[index1].Twelth;
                      }
                    } else {
                        endChoice = dsobj[index1].Eleventh;
                    }
                  } else {
                    endChoice = dsobj[index1].Tenth;
                  }
                } else {
                    endChoice = dsobj[index1].Ninth;
                }
              } else {
                endChoice = dsobj[index1].Eigth;
              }
            } else {
                endChoice = dsobj[index1].Seventh;
            }
          } else {
            endChoice = dsobj[index1].Sixth;
          }
        } else {
            endChoice = dsobj[index1].Fifth;
        }
      } else {
        endChoice = dsobj[index1].Fourth;
      }
    } else {
        endChoice = dsobj[index1].Third;
    }
  } else {
    endChoice = dsobj[index1].Second;
  }
} else {
    endChoice = dsobj[index1].First;
}
  } else {
endChoice = dsobj[index1].First;
  }
} else {
    continue;
}
};
return endChoice
}

 function displayPref(index,id,wd) {
endChoice = getPref(index);

if (wd === dsobj[index].RDO1 || wd === dsobj[index].RDO2) {
    $('#'+id+'').append("<td>None</td>");
} else {
    $('#'+id+'').append("<td>"+endChoice+"</td>");
}
```

}

Comment: @ Hintshigen after applying all your rules what is desire output?

Comment: Have you looked at the utility [jQuery.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)?

Comment: @ozil The desired output would be the persons name and then the choice listed next to that, but only 1 person can have 1 choice, so two people could not have choice 6 displayed

Comment: @urbz I have not, but looking at it now thank you

Comment: @ Hintshigen what would be you final `object` `var People = ??`

Comment: I really don't understand what needs to be in the output.

Comment: I added additional code to try and clarify

Comment: This still makes no sense. What are you trying to accomplish? Sort the array by a field? If you have this set of data, show us what should be the answer for this set of data.

Comment: @Alexey In this specific example shown it should display as follows:  Person1 5  Person2 6  Person3 9  This is because both Person3 and Person2 both have selected 6 as their first choice but Person2 has the lower SN number therefore the choice is awarded to them and Person3 moves to their second choice where the check is supposed to done again to make sure that it doesn't conflict

Comment: I also don't understand exactly what is the expected result, but it sounds like you could use recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the following function to suit your needs. I implemented it, to fill an object with the winner for each choice and for every choice name:

```
var winners = {};

function getChoiceWinner(choiceName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < People.length; i++) {
        var choice = People[i][choiceName];
        if(!winners[choiceName]) winners[choiceName] = {};
        winners[choiceName][choice] = People[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < People.length; j++) {
            if (winners[choiceName][choice][choiceName] == People[j][choiceName]) {
                winners[choiceName][choice] = People[j]["SN"] < winners[choiceName][choice]["SN"] ? People[j] : winners[choiceName][choice];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zddx5tz/)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to change this slightly to display the information I was looking for. I did not think of this solution as a possibility and appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

After a little work around what you required I've got a solution .. I think .

The output is a little messy, but since your array will be bigger you'll get everything grouped by `First` then by `SN`

```
function groupBy( array , f )
{
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}

var groupedByFirst = groupBy(People, function(item)
{
  return [item.First];
});

var finalGrouping = new Array;
 for (i = 0; i <= groupedByFirst.length-1; i++) {
     var test = groupBy(groupedByFirst[i], function(item) {
        return [item.SN]
    });
    finalGrouping.push(test);
}
console.log(finalGrouping)
```

Here's the fiddle so you can test it:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lszq8tgb/13/)

The difference between this and the last answer is that this is dynamic. So basically you can keep going into the array and sort for different properties.

Also, it's way more maintainable if you want to change the properties.

So, for the thing you require, to list the properties.. just print the array by order and you have everything listed by `First` and then by `SN`

Comment: Wow, this one is very nice as well, thank you for taking the time to delve into it and it will definitely help with the expanded array. If I had the reputation to upvote you I would. Instead you have my thanks!